# Configurable products in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

My requirement is adding the same simple products in 2 different configurable products with the prices of the simple products to be different.
For e.g Simple product A added inside Configurable product B has price $20.
Whereas, The same Simple product A added inside Configurable product C has price $30.
How can i achieve this in magento 2.
I want to also know that, when editing the configurations for simple products inside configurable products here https://prnt.sc/t1we8i
When i select the option "Apply unique prices by attrbute" https://prnt.sc/t1wev8 and give different price for the product. It not only changes the price here https://prnt.sc/t1wfx8 but it also changes the price of the default simple product. https://prnt.sc/t1whli
I don't want that.
Can anybody help me in this. If my requirements are not cleared, please comment, i will again explain.

Comment: This used to be possible in Magento 1 but in Magento 2 configurable products are just containers for simple products with no pricing option. You should try and create a simple product for each saleable product you have and use product attributes for the varations.

Comment: Actually i have migrated my site from 1.9 to 2.3. It will be difficult to go back and again make simple products. Hence i was searching for some solution

Comment: You can duplicate the simple products in Magento 2 and make the changes to price or attributes and the manually add them to the configurable.

Comment: I have 2500 products, duplicating is also a major task. Is there any simple way for duplicating the prodcuts? some scripts or anything? in magento 1

Comment: I would look at using the built in import system to import the new simple products. There is no simple way around this, configurable products in Magento 2 are completely different to Magento 1. Use this opportunity to redesign and improve your product presentation.

Comment: I would like to do this in magento 1 first, so when final data migration is done. everything is simple. How can i duplicate the products in simple way in magento 1.9. I was planning to export all the simple products and change the sku and price or the data i want to change keeping rest of the things same and then import that new sku's. Can you tell me what happens with the url's? duplicate products will have same url??

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can config this way in Magento 1 but not in Magento 2. Therefore, you should duplicate A and add it into C.